# Too many redirects

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

I have an app on Heroku which I would like to point to with two different URLs. I use CloudFlare as my name server. My first domain has 8 records; 2 CNAME, 6 MX and one TXT. It looks like so:

```
CNAME <my_site.co.uk> is an alias of <my_app.herokuapp.com>
CNAME www             is an alias of <my_app.herokuapp.com>
MX    <my_site.co.uk> ...
MX    <my_site.co.uk> ...
MX    <my_site.co.uk> ...
MX    <my_site.co.uk> ...
MX    <my_site.co.uk> ...
TXT   google._domainkey ...
```

When I hit `my_site.co.uk` it loads as expected. When I try it for my second domain I get the error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

The DNS records for both sites are identical apart from their respective URLs. What's the problem?

Comment: This is an issue with webserver configuration, not DNS. As such, all we can tell you based on the information provided is that your webserver is serving a chain of HTTP redirects so long that the browser is eventually giving up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the DNS records were identical for each URL, the crypto settings (`https://www.cloudflare.com/a/crypto/<your_url>`) were not. The working URL had full SSL while the non-working one had flexible. Setting both to full now allows one access to the site.

Comment: That crypto setting has caused me a lot of similar issues, it's the first thing I check when something weird happens now.